# ASP.NET Core OAuth with basic auth for TokenEndpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use ASP.Net Core 2.2 with OAuth authentication. To use OAuth I use the `AddOAuth` method in the `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`in Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Provider";
})            
.AddCookie()
.AddOAuth("Provider", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Provider:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Provider:ClientSecret"];
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://api.provider.net/auth/code";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.provider.net/auth/token";
});
```

The problem is, that when the middleware tries to get an authorization code by using the `TokenEndpoint`, I receive a HTTP 401 because the provider expects a basic authentication header at this endpoint.

My question is, how can I tell the middleware to add a basic auth header to the TokenEndpoint request?

Comment: I think this question is similar enough to guide you to a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994176/jwtbearerhandler-with-authorization-header-for-discovery-endpoint/52999219.

Comment: This problem still exists today. It is strange because an authorization server support for client_id/client_credential authentication is optional according to the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Kirk Larkin Thanks for posting the link, this helped me alot to came up with a solution!

I  created a `DelegateHandler` which adds a basic authentication header if the request is send to the `TokenEndpoint`:

```
public class AuthorizingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly OAuthOptions _options;
    public AuthorizingHandler(HttpMessageHandler inner, OAuthOptions options)
        : base(inner)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(request.RequestUri == new Uri(_options.TokenEndpoint))
        {
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_options.ClientId + ":" + _options.ClientSecret));

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {credentials}");
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This `DelegateHandler` is used in the `ConfigureService` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Provider";
    })            
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOAuth("Provider", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Provider:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Provider:ClientSecret"];
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://api.provider.net/auth/code";
        options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.provider.net/auth/token";

        var innerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new AuthorizingHandler(innerHandler, options);

        //...
    });

    // ...
}
```